# Can we automate Weblogic deployment process?

Tags: weblogic

I want to automate the deployment process of weblogic as everytime I have to first stop,delete,upload and start the war.

Comment: Yes. WLST is what you are looking for. It is a tool that you can use to run Jython scripts in which you have scripted the whole deployment process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate the deployment process using `WLST` where you need to execute `jython` script.

The script will be executed under WLST environment, which you may find at below location

```
  <obiee_home>/u01/app/obiee/oracle_common/common/bin
```

You can refer good article for complete [deployment process](https://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/automate-wls-console-tasks-with-wlst).